# Multilingual online shop - best practices

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, multilingual

So, I am building multilingual webstore on Laravel 9.x. I'm creating database structure for my project, and I am at the point where I need to implement several languages.
**Here's my idea**
I've created structure like: 
ID:            `1`
Title:        `[ { "en" : "Title"}, { "fr" : "Titre" } ]`
Content:  `[ { "en" : "Content"}, { "fr" : "Contenu"} ]`
I will get data like that:

```
echo json_decode($data, true)['en']['title'];
```

And now I'm wondering, if the performance (with content with about 7k characters per language) will be much worse than solution like:
ID:                  `1`
Title_En:        `"Title"`
Title_Fr:         `"Titre"`
Content_En:  `"Content"`
Content_Fr:   `"Contenu"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't structure it that way.  Instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Xlations (
    xlation_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    language CHAR(2) eg "en" or maybe CHAR(5) eg "fr_ca"
    title...
    content...
    PRIMARY KEY(language, xlation_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Somewhere, you need to assign new ids, since one xlation_id will be used for all the languages for a given title/content.

I would guess that the lookups would be similar to

```
SELECT content FROM xlations
    WHERE language = 'es'   -- Probably set when the user logs in
      AND xlation_id = 17;  -- a constant based on context
```